# Having problem with Discord.js addRole() Function

Tags: javascript, node.js, oop, typeerror, discord.js

I want my Discord bot to set role as the user input corresponding role args, e.g: !role btcm, !role nccm, etc.

I'm having a problem with the discord.js addRole() function as I can't see its documentation on discord.js.org.
The console show `TypeError: member.addRole is not a function`

```
module.exports = message => {
    const member = message.member;

    switch(message.content.split(" ")[1]){
        case "btcm":
            roleID = "THE ID No.1"
        case "nccm":
            roleID = "THE ID No.2"
        case "guest":
            roleID = "THE ID No.3"

        let roleAtts = message.guild.roles.cache.get(roleID);
        member.addRole(roleAtts);
        channel.send("Successfully set a role");
    }
}
```

Comment: If an answer solves your issue then please accept it to let others know what worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since discord.js v12, you need to use [`roles.add()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMemberRoleManager?scrollTo=add) instead of `addRole()`

```js
member.roles.add(roleAtts);
```

Answer (score 1):

The method is `member.roles.add()` instead of `member.addRole()`.